# Unity keep references to model parts after updating the model file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple script that I added to the root of my 3D model. In the script, I have several serialized fields that reference different parts of the model.

The problem is when I update my model (by overwriting the original file), all the references get deleted and I must reassign them.

Is there a way to work around it and save the references? (The model's hierarchy doesn't change when updating the model)

One solution that I thought about (but is inefficient) is to a string representing the path to the transform with an Enum that tells me the type, and on Start find all the transforms and call `GetComponent`.
It would work, but will be very inefficient…

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't able to find any seamless solution, so I created an editor script that helped me transfer the references to parts in the new model.

Because the code is specific to my use case, I will post here 2 static functions that I used.

```cs
private void ReplacePart<T>(string partPath, Transform destModel, Action<T> setFunction) where T : Component
{
    Transform transform = destModel.Find(partPath);
    T component = transform.gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
    setFunction(component);
}
private string GetFullPath(Component o, Transform sourceModel)
{
    Transform transform = o.transform;
    if (transform == null)
        return string.Empty;
    var objects = new Stack<string>();
    do
    {
        objects.Push(transform.name);
        transform = transform.parent;
    } while (transform != null && transform.name != sourceModel.name);
    return string.Join("/", objects);
}
```